# how to set use angular methods without prefixing word 'angular'

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

Hi i'm using angularjs library for [local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/blob/master/src/angular-local-storage.js)

I've added it to my project using regular

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'customFilters', 'LocalStorageModule']);
```

But while I'm  trying to run the code, i have an error "isObject is not defined", "isDefinded is not defined"

All those are angular method and would work fine if i prefix it with angular.isDefined, but the library was written this way, so the question is What i do wrong? how to prevent using "angular" word before each method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Functions `isDefined` and `isObject` are actually shortcut references to angular `angular.isDefined` and `angular.isObject`. Those references are defined in the file `src/common.js` which during build process (check [`concat:dist` Grunt task](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L26)) gets concatenated with `src/angular-local-storage.js` and wrapped into closure:

```
concat: {
  options: {
    banner: '<%= meta.banner %>' + '\n' +
      '(function ( window, angular, undefined ) {' + '\n',
    footer: '})( window, window.angular );'
  },
  dist: {
    src: ['src/common.js', 'src/angular-local-storage.js'],
    dest: '<%= dirs.dest %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
  }
},
```

That's why those convenience functions are available in library code, but not outside. You cannot use them unless you defined them yourself somewhere in you local scope.